# Serialize iqueryable

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, viewstate, iqueryable

I have an ascx user control with and Entity Framework IQueryable property like this:

```
  public IQueryable<Category> DataSource
    {
        get { return ViewState["Category"] as IQueryable; }
        set { ViewState["Category"] = value; }
    }
```

As you can see, I tried to use ViewState to persist the value and don't have to set it on every postback but it says type is not marked as serializable...

how can I mark this as serializable?, is it recomendable to save this property on ViewState or is it better to set in on every postback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, `IQueryable` is not serializable because it's not data. The query is like the means to an end, not the end itself.

I would save the result set in the Cache, not ViewState.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely *have* to save the data in the ViewState you could always serialize it yourself or flatten it in some other way.